# Android: actionbar triggers spinner issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

Android: 
I would like to create an Spinner triggered from the ActionBar. 
I am using the following code. 
What I see is that on initialisation the menu-item 0 (without a click) is run. 
I also see that selecting a further menu-item-1 is not working. 
What's wrong with the following code?

Both problems I have localized in the code:

Res/menu/main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner">
</item>
```

The code in the MainActivity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    String[] spinnerEntries = new String[]{ "Item-1", "Item-2", "Item-3"};
    MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate( R.menu.main, menu);
    mSpinnerItem1 = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_spinner1);
    View view1 = mSpinnerItem1.getActionView();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinnerEntries);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    if (view1 instanceof Spinner)         {
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view1;
        spinner.setAdapter( adapter);
        spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner); 
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch( arg2) { 
                case 0: 
                    // Problem 1: 
                    // first this code is executed before any click happened
                    //
                    // Problem 2: 
                    // then ... the code is executed only after I clicked first 
                    //    on item-2 or item-3 and then to item-1
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //     code for option 2 etc.             
                    }
                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

when you set `Adapter` to `Spinner` and when `Spinner` is added to window(added to `ActionBar`), then `Spinner` will pick the first item `View` (whose position is zero in Adapter) from the `Adapter` and call `OnItemSelectedListener`(first received callback from `Spinner` irrespective of you have selected or not, Spinner will select).

Second,

If you select the item from the `Spinner` which is already previously selected, then you won't receive `OnItemSelectedListener` callback from the `Spinner`...

Comment: Thank you! 

First: 
How can I then just show the 3 items before 1 is called? 

Second: 
I can click on item-2. After a moment again on item-2 ... and in both cases the actions of item-2 are done. 
What is the difference here? 

Same applies to item-1 ... after first clicking on other items.